# Ghostscript converted PDF not rendered corectly with pdfium

Tags: pdf, rendering, ghostscript, pdfa, pdfium

I have a problem with some pdf documents I convert with Ghostsript to pdf/a documents. If the original document contains subseted fonts, the document is not correctly displayed in Chrome (pdfium) after converting. The chars will be displayed as squares.

In Adobe PDF Reader the output will be displayed correctly. Maybe the attached files can help you.

[original PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SzakktFjZ-6EiprqURLjLY4sOHFt56Xa/view?usp=sharing)

[converted PDF/A](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bq3qu4QleS2LKEzsQrw1QemgzaBgYJ1_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: That would be a problem with Chrome then, I'd suggest you raise a bug report with Google. Note that the PDF/A standard does not permit fonts to be subset, so Ghostscript won't further subset them, but if you start with a subset font, we cannot undo it. I'd guess the problem with Chrome is that the original contains fonts, while the created file contains CIDFonts.

Comment: Many thank's for your fast replay Ken. I raised a ticket at Google.

Comment: FWIW I noticed that Ghostscript has rewritten the TrueType fonts, they are still valid, (and the text has not been re-encoded) but its possible there's 'something' about the regenerated fonts that Chrome doesn't like I've no idea what it would be though.